# Book where main character has female ai in mind and nano armor

Tags: story-identification, books, artificial-intelligence, mars

I read this book around 2010. It’s set in the future on, I believe, Mars. The main character has an ai implanted in his mind that’s described as a woman. He also has nanotechnology armor that I remember is described as moving and concentrating at the point of impact. I believe the main character is also missing an eye? I don’t remember any of the plot aside from there being giant insect like creatures and the protagonist and ai bantering often.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Are the insectoids friendly or hostile?  What is the protagonist trying to accomplish?  Why does he have an implanted AI?  Do you recall the cover art?